# Hide price excluding tax when price field is empty in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have a setup. For products, I display prices with VAT (info added in the suffix). However, I must include a net price under this price (only in single-product-view). In addition, I have products that are without a price and with them using the Call For Price plugin to display a button to send a price inquiry.

I display the net price adding:

```
<?php echo woocommerce_price ($ product-> get_price_excluding_tax ()); ?>
```

added in the template `/woocommerce/single-product/price.php`.

The problem is that in the case of a product without a price, I still see this value without tax (net) with the amount of 0.00. This one with VAT is deleted automatically.

I try also:

```
<?php if(woocommerce_price ($product-> get_price_excluding_tax ()) != '0.00') // If price is not equal to 0.00
{ echo woocommerce_price ($product-> get_price_excluding_tax ()); }
?>
```

and

```
<?php if( !empty(woocommerce_price ($product-> get_price_excluding_tax ()))) { echo woocommerce_price ($product-> get_price_excluding_tax ()); } ?>
```

Still 0,00 is visible.

How could I remove this net price in products that do not have the price indicated? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **Woocommerce version 3**, `woocommerce_price()` function is outdated and deprecated. It has been replaced by `wc_price()` formatting function.

Same thing for `get_price_excluding_tax()` method. It has been replaced by this function *(where `$product` is an instance of the `WC_Product` object)*:

```
 wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product );
```

So the correct code should be:

```
<?php 
    $price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product );
    echo $price_excl_tax > 0 || ! empty( $price_excl_tax ) ? wc_price( $price_excl_tax ) . __(' netto') : '';
?>
```

Tested and works

---

**Before** Woocommerce version 3, you will use:

```
<?php 
    $price_excl_tax = $product->get_price_excluding_tax();
    echo $price_excl_tax > 0 || ! empty( $price_excl_tax ) ? woocommerce_price( $price_excl_tax ) . __(' netto') : '';
?>
```

Comment: Great it works! If I want to add a "netto" after price in which part of code I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php if (!empty(floatval(woocommerce_price($product>get_price_excluding_tax()))))
 { echo woocommerce_price($product->get_price_excluding_tax(); } ?>
```

Comment: In this option it is not visible on product with price